# How to ignore lowercase and uppercase in order clause in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this function for getting users from database :

```
function get_users_limited($offset, $limit)
{
    $q = $this->db->select('*')
              ->from('users')
              ->join('user_profiles', 'user_profiles.user_id = users.id'  )
              ->order_by('users.username asc')
              ->limit($limit, $offset)
              ->get();
    return $q;
}
```

And I want to order the results by username asc, but the problem is that it makes difference between A and a and B and b etc.

The problem is that the result looks like this:

```
Albert
Bob
Caesar
axnGuy
blackboy83
c3p0
```

and I want this:

```
Albert
axnGuy
Bob
blackboy83
Caesar
c3p0
```

Any advice how to ingnore lowercase and uppercase in CodeIgniter?

**I need CI specific solution!**

Comment: may i ask any reason to do this ?

Comment: What exactly do you don't understand? Be specific.

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,225465 - Solution

Comment: Which code from the link have you tried in CI active record, becouse it is not working for me? have you tried in CI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your php there, and you don't specify what charset you're using.  Also, it's not specifically mentioned, but I assume we're talking MySQL here.

Assuming MySQL, suppose you're using a charset of utf8.

You can choose a different collation (valid for utf8) in your select such as

```
SELECT `name` COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci as `name` FROM `owners`;
```

Here the table is utf8 charset, and I use the utf8_unicode_ci (ci for case insensitive) collation mode on the `name` column.

If you were using the default charset of latin1 you'd do something more like:

```
SELECT `name` COLLATE latin1_general_ci as `name` FROM `owners`;
```

etc.

Totally unfamiliar with your PHP, but I'd assume it'd look something like this:

```
function get_users_limited($offset, $limit)
{
    $q = $this->db->select('users.username COLLATE latin1_general_ci as c1, user_profiles.* ')
              ->from('users')
              ->join('user_profiles', 'user_profiles.user_id = users.id'  )
              ->order_by('c1 asc')
              ->limit($limit, $offset)
              ->get();
    return $q;
}
```

Specifying the collation subset of your charset doesn't set or change the default collation on that column/table.

Comment: If this does not work because of escaping issues, you can use ''$this->db->select('users.username COLLATE latin1_general_ci as c1, user_profiles.*', FALSE)'' to avoid CI automatically escaping column names.

Comment: I got this error COLLATION 'latin1_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'

Comment: As I said, you did not mention which charset you were using.  If `utf8` you need to change `latin1_general_ci` in the `db->select` to `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Comment: The charset determines which characters you can store, while the collation mode refers to the rules for sorting them in order by clauses. As such a collation mode is specific to its charset, but a charset could have many different collation modes.

Answer (score 0):

This relates to the collation of the database. Change it to some _ci variant (case insensitive) and try the same query.

Comment: That is not possible, I am using search and ther can be some problems in the future. I just need it for this one listing function.

Comment: What problems can it cause?

Comment: In the end, that active record query is just a plain old sql query. CI won't be affected by changing the collation (wich is not the same as the charset). Obviously it will change the ordering of all results for that table, if you change it on the table level. If you change it at the connection level from /application/config/database.php obviously will be system-wide.

Comment: The code provided by the accepted answer (wich is not mine) is already the one I was thinking of.